# Check hashed email addresses in the database

Tags: php, mysql

The site I'm working on stores e-mail addresses in a hashed form by `password_hash()`
I know it's meant for passowrds, but the site is already up, so no going back.

Now when a new user tries to register, I need to check if the e-mail address that the user is using isn't already in the database. But since all e-mail addresses are hashed, I can't simply use:

```
$mail_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM userbase WHERE email='$email'");
                    $mail_num = mysql_num_rows($mail_query);
                    if ($mail_num != 0) {
                    $error = 'This email address is already in use.';
```

Is there any way to do it?

The site uses old MySQL api.

Comment: if you actually *do* use password_hash in the secure way it's meant to, you have to *retreive and test every. single. mail. address.* in your database. sorry. the question is: *why do you even hash the email-address*? what do you do if you want to - i know, preposterous idea - want to send an *email* to one of your users?

Comment: The idea was in case of database breach, user email addresses would remain unreadable.

Comment: So how do you email your users?

Comment: @Sammitch apparently, he doesn't

Comment: I don't. Email is just used for password reset. You can check hashed email against username by `!password_verify`. But I can't check hashed email against plain text email, since plain text email isn't stored...

Comment: @Menel well, there *is* a "going back", which you should do, but which you won't like. add a new "plain_mail"-column, force your users to re-validate their email-address at the next login and store the plain email. the thought of a security breach is commendable, but it's completely in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll have to roll back. Is there a good way to store emails in encrypted form, but in such a way so they can be checked normally?

Comment: @Menel i think the aggreed best practice is to just store them as plain text (everybody: tell me if i'm wrong here). but if you definitely want to *do* that: you could use saltless hashes - but beware of collisions. or you could encrypt with a server-wide password - which however, in a case of DB-leak, probably is leaked as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only way, but very baaaad is to get AAAAALLLL emails and check them all... Sorry, don't even remember MySQL_* functions, but first you need to do such query:

`SELECT email FROM userbase`

and then, when you get all emails do loop and use `password_verify` on every single email... So in your loop you should have something like:

```
if(password_verify($email,$hash)) {
    echo "Email is already in use!";
    break;
}
```

that's it. Good luck. But I don't like such hashing: what if you need to remind users password?

Comment: "remind users password"? as in: send them their old password, which was stored as plain-text next to the safely hashed email-address? *never* remind passwords, *only* reset them. ;)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yep, sorry. My English... ;D well, even if you want, you can't remind password that is hashed with password_hash :D

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I think he meant "how do you email your users the password reset link/token?" or, for that matter, email them at all?

Comment: @Sammitch same idea: I meant that you can't email your users then (password reset, news, other stuff, whatever).

Comment: password reset actually works, they just have to type in their email which is then checked against their username, but the problem comes when I wanna check if someone is not registering with already registered email address

Comment: @Menel my method is the only think i can create now... I don't believe there is another way to do this :)